# Configuring LDAP Server for fail over scenario

Tags: ldap

I want to configure LDAP over SSL. I know how to configure it.  I am going to use this LDAP server to authenticate user at time of logging in my web site.  But In case if any error/exception that may occur due to LDAP over SSL ( like certificate expired, empty certificate store ), I DONT WANT USER WILL BE PREVENTED TO LOGIN JUST BECAUSE OF MERE SSL exception. What I want to do in that case is  to use LDAP WITHOUT SSL. Can I configure one LDAP server to run with and without SSL at different port simultenously? Or I must use two different LDAP server (and so machine) and arrange some fail over mechanism that if one fails than automatically request will be serverd by other server (without SSL)?
Please help me regarding how to address this scenario.
Above description might be not detailed but if you want I can describe more.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Product/configuration support is off-topic, stackoverflow.com is for programming questions

Comment: This question does not belong here. It should be moved to serverfault. And as far as there is no LDAP implementation specified in your question, if you are running OpenLDAP, yes it is possible. Check `man slapd`, it is explicitly specified

Comment: Thanks @Esteban for your suggestion. I will delete this post from this forum.